# Identify the functional equation

Tags: calculus

My attempt: I wrote the equation of a circle for x belongs to [0,xo]. But I had no clue about what should I do for x belongs to (xo,infinity).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just after the general shape, working radially will reveal a more intuitive set of solutions. By radially I mean polar i.e. $(r,\theta)$. You can then convert back to $(x,y)$ afterwards.

You need to find two equations:

- The first is the circle centred around (R,0)

  $r_1(\theta) = 2Rcos\theta$
- The second is a function that is infinity at $\theta = 2\pi$ and $\theta = 0$, but $0$ at $\theta = \pi$

  $r_2(\theta) = tan^2(\frac{\theta + \pi}{2})$

You now need to scale between these functions, using a third function which only has values between 0 and 1.

$S(\theta) \; r_1(\theta) \; + \; (1-S(\theta)) \; r_2(\theta)$

The purpose of this scale function is to cause $r_1(\theta)$ to be "in charge" when $\theta$ is near $\pi$ and $r_2(\theta)$ to be "in charge" when $\theta$ is near $0$ or $2\pi$.

$S(\theta) = sin^{12}(\theta/2)$

- Note: The functions I have provided can be changed for others that do the same jobs. Good luck finding the exact shape you're after.